# What is the JAX-WS annotation to return an object

Tags: java, jax-ws

I want to expose a java class as a JAX-WS service. This works fine if I return a String from a method, but I can't figure out how to return an object. Looking at Oracle's example (https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WSGET/jax-ws-examples.htm#WSGET117)
I thought this code should work:

```
@WebService
public class CCService implements CCServiceLocal {

     /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */
     public CCService() {
     }


    @WebMethod
    @WebResult(name="ApplicationConstantReturnMessage")
    public ApplicationConstant getConst( ) {
        return new ApplicationConstant("Group", "SubGroup", "Id", "Code", "Text", "Description" );
    }

}
```

But when I invoke it with SOAPUi, I get an empty response:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <getConstResponse xmlns="http://test.cc.com/" xmlns:ns2="http://example.org/complex">
         <ns2:ApplicationConstantReturnMessage/>
      </getConstResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

Here is the ApplicationConstant class:

```
public class ApplicationConstant {

public  ApplicationConstant(String group, String subGroup, String id, String code, String text, String desc ) {
    this.group = group;
    this.subGroup = subGroup;
    this.id = id;
    this.text = text;
    this.code = code;
    this.desc = desc;
}

public  String group() { return group; }
public  String subGroup() { return subGroup; }
public  String constantIdentifier() { return id; }
public  String constantText() { return text; }
public  String constantCode() { return code; }
public  String constantDesc() { return desc; }


private String group;
private String subGroup;
private String id;
private String text;
private String code;
private String desc;    

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found it. I needed some annotations in my ApplicationConstant class, along with a default no-arg constructor.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="ApplicationConstant")
public class ApplicationConstant {

public ApplicationConstant() {
}

public  ApplicationConstant(String group, String subGroup, String id, String code, String text, String desc ) {
    this.group = group;
    this.subGroup = subGroup;
    this.id = id;
    this.text = text;
    this.code = code;
    this.desc = desc;
}

public  String group() { return group; }
public  String subGroup() { return subGroup; }
public  String constantIdentifier() { return id; }
public  String constantText() { return text; }
public  String constantCode() { return code; }
public  String constantDesc() { return desc; }


@XmlElement private String group;
@XmlElement private String subGroup;
@XmlElement private String id;
@XmlElement private String text;
@XmlElement private String code;
@XmlElement private String desc;    

}
```